# str_replace - Only variables can be passed by reference

Tags: php

What is causing this error?

**Fatal error**:  Only variables can be passed by reference in **/var/www/application
/lib/testing/imageMaker/imageMaker.php** on line **24**

```
$x=str_replace ($s1,'',$s2);
$y=str_replace ($s1,'',$s2, 1 ); //Line 24
```

Comment: Maybe check the manual. The count argument is by reference

Comment: Where does it say passed by reference?  Is it indicated by the `&`?

Comment: Read the description: "If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described here: [PHP Manual: str_replace](http://us.php.net/str_replace)

`count`

> If passed, this will be set to the number of replacements performed.

You cannot pass the `literals` and rather pass the reference:

```
$x=str_replace ($s1,'',$s2);
$y=str_replace ($s1,'',$s2, $count);
echo $count;
```

Comment: I haven't used PHP in a while, but your answer does pass `$count` by reference either. You need to use `str_replace($s1, '', $s2, &$count);` to pass a reference to the `$count` variable, rather than the literal value of `$count`.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Ahh, good catch. I was way over my head for a moment ;)

Comment: Spencer is mistaken. Despite the name, you do not define the reference when passing the variable. Doing so will generate a fatal error in PHP 5.4, and a warning in 5.3. You should change this back to `$count`. Read the note near the top of this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @rjdown So its safe to write it the way I had written before?

Comment: Yes, it is the only way.